# Why is my foxtail palm not growing new fronds?

Tags: diagnosis, palm

My foxtail palm is no longer growing new fronds. Some of the older ones grew stunted but the fronds are dark green. I replanted a 15ft palm about 2 years ago and fertilize it every 3 months. The fronds look a little wimpy and not bushy the last 4 months or so. I added manganese about 2 months ago but not sure what is wrong or what to do.enter image description here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add a picture or two including a close up of the underside of the leaves?